# How do I install pyOpenSSL on Mac OS X?

Tags: pyopenssl

I am using Titanium 3.0 and trying to update pyOpenSSL.  I have checked the python website and only see downloadable links for Windows.  In the Tianium forum they say that "If you installed Python using MacPorts or Homebrew, use the same utility to install PyOpenSSL and PyCrypto." I tried using homebrew and did "brew install pyopenssl" and got the error message "No available formula for pyopenssl".  Any advice?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try using easy_install

`easy_install PyOpenSSL`

`easy_install PyCrypto`

Comment: I was getting "'openssl/e_os2.h' file not found" errors which were prohibiting `easy_install PyOpenSSL` from completing. Running `brew link openssl` and `brew link openssl --force` before solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Install via Homebrew:

```
brew install openssl env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" pip install cryptography
```

This answer is from https://chriskief.com/2014/03/25/installing-cryptography-via-pip-with-macports-or-homebrew/comment-page-1/#comment-2809