# IoT Azure Edge ContextualVersionConflict: pyOpenSSL

Tags: azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-suite

I am following the **Quickstart Azure IoT Edge** tutorial and in the Section [Configure the IoT Edge runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart#configure-the-iot-edge-runtime).

When I configure the runtime with the IoT Edge device connection string

```
iotedgectl setup --connection-string "{device connection string}" --nopass
```

(I changed the connection string) I get the following result

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/iotedgectl", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(coremain())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/edgectl/__init__.py", line 23, in coremain
    version = pkg_resources.require(PACKAGE_NAME)[0].version
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 959, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 851, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyOpenSSL 0.13.1 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python), Requirement.parse('pyOpenSSL>=0.14'), set(['docker']))
```

That does not allow me to continue with the command

```
iotedgectl start
```

I looked at the file ***init*.py** From line 857-859 There is:

```
        # Register the new requirements needed by req
        for new_requirement in new_requirements:
            required_by[new_requirement].add(req.project_name)
```

Lines 848 - 851

```
 if dist not in req:
                # Oops, the "best" so far conflicts with a dependency
                dependent_req = required_by[req]
                raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
```

Line 959

```
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
```

What do I need to change there? Or what needs to be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before installing iotedgectl, you already have a lower version of pyOpenSSL installed, which does not meet iotedgectl's version requirement but precedes the higher version of pyOpenSSL installed along with iotedgectl.

You can check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46439342/498996) to learn how to make Python reference the higher version of pyOpenSSL first.

In addition, it seems that you are working on macOS. If so, please refer to [Quickstart: Deploy your first IoT Edge module to a Linux or Mac device - preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart-linux), instead of [Quickstart: Deploy your first IoT Edge module from the Azure portal to a Windows device - preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-edge/quickstart#configure-the-iot-edge-runtime).

Comment: You are right, now is working. First I had to fix the error regarding matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
matplotlib 1.3.1 requires tornado, which is not installed. By upgrading matplotlib "pip install --user --upgrade matplotlib" and then I had no more errors and I could continue with the configuration sudo pip install -U azure-iot-edge-runtime-ctl

Answer (score 1):

From the message,it shows that the pyOpenSSL is too old, it needs 0.14 or later.

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/local/bin/iotedgectl", line 11, in <module>
>     sys.exit(coremain())
>   File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/edgectl/__init__.py", line 23, in coremain
>     version = pkg_resources.require(PACKAGE_NAME)[0].version
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
>  line 959, in require
>     needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
>   File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources/__init__.py",
>  line 851, in resolve
>     raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
> pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (pyOpenSSL 0.13.1 (/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python),
>  Requirement.parse('pyOpenSSL>=0.14'), set(['docker']))
> ```

You can use the following command to upgrade the pyOpenSSL:

```
pip install --upgrade pyOpenSSL
```

If the problem can not be resolved, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: I upgraded, but got the error. I added on the question

Comment: Thank you, now is working. I had to upgrade matplotlib