# OpenSSL not found on MacOS Sierra

Tags: php, mongodb, macos, openssl, macos-sierra

I am trying to install a PHP MongoDB driver but the installation is failing because it cannot locate the OpenSSL.

```
/Users/username/mongo-php-driver/src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.c:24:10: fatal error: 'openssl/sha.h' file not found
#include <openssl/sha.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [src/libmongoc/src/mongoc/mongoc-crypto-openssl.lo] Error 1
```

I read that this has something to do with the latest version of MacOS? Is there a way to do it, as I really need to install this driver.

Comment: See [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830) on the Apple Stack Exchange or [Compilation and Installation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Compilation_and_Installation) on the OpenSSL wiki.

Comment: These may apply as well, if you have already installed OpenSSL: [How do I install pyOpenSSL on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14361569), [Updating openssl in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18752409), [Python referencing old SSL version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24323858), [Python and OpenSSL version reference issue on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37690054), [Python 3.3 and Installing PyOpenSSL on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21899573), [Using Python with homebrew on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25441252), etc...

Comment: How are you trying to install this driver?

Answer (score 20):

This is the only solution that worked for me.

```
cd /usr/local/include 
ln -s ../opt/openssl/include/openssl .
```

Source: https://www.anintegratedworld.com/mac-osx-fatal-error-opensslsha-h-file-not-found/

Comment: Another source form Github https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/issues/523

Comment: This is the best answer for me.
Was checking on same issue in #erlang on macOs big Sur

Comment: I'm on macOS 12.3 and `/usr/local/include` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 10):

You’ll need to install OpenSSL using [homebrew](http://brew.sh/), and tell homebrew to create symlinks:

```
brew install openssl
brew link openssl --force
```

If you don’t already have homebrew installed, you can get it by running this:

```
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

And before all that, if you haven’t already installed XCode and the XCode command-line tools:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: OpenSSL is already installed, it just cannot be found by the installed package for some reason.

Comment: When you say it’s already installed, do you mean you installed it with homebrew? Because if it‘s not the version installed with homebrew, I think you may not have the necessary header files installed. (Even if you the have OpenSSL binaries installed, that doesn’t necessarily mean you’ll have the header files; you need to ensure that OpenSSL is installed in a way that also installs the header files.)

Comment: Don't forget to set your environment variables `export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/expat/lib" && export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/expat/include" && export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/expat/include"`

Comment: As @sideshowbarker said, maybe you need to run the `brew install openssl` command anyway. Then, since OpenSSL is keg-only, it has to be referred from an environment variable (I.e., the `bin` folder of installation directory should be added to the system `PATH` variable - It may be a bit different in your system, it’s because it depends on its version.). Here is a valuable article about this: [Installing OpenSSL library on macOS Catalina](https://yasar-yy.medium.com/installing-openssl-library-on-macos-catalina-6777a2e238a6)

Answer (score 4):

First install `libressl` using brew:

```
brew install libressl
```

Then run the following:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/lib \
-L/usr/local/opt/expat/lib" && export CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ \
-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/expat/include" && export \
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include/ -I/usr/local/include \
-I/usr/local/opt/expat/include"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use environment variable `C_INCLUDE_PATH` to tell the compiler to include the path to openssl header files.

For example, if you just want to do it once:

`sudo C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/local/opt/openssl/include pecl install mongo`

---

Reference: [charles.lescampeurs.org](http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2013/06/18/add-c-header-include-path-pecl)