# Linking OpenSSL 1.1.0e installed manually to python2.7

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, ssl, openssl

I'm trying to update my Python SSL, but I'm unable to do it.

When I check the openssl version in terminal I get:

OpenSSL 1.1.0e  16 Feb 2017

And when I check the python ssl library with:

```
python -c "import ssl; print ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION"
```

I get:

```
OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017
```

I already installed Python from homebrew, with:

```
rew install python --with-brewed-openssl
```

This is the version I'm running:

```
Python 2.7.13
```

I installed OpenSSL 1.1.0e manually, how can I link it to python?

Comment: [How do I install pyOpenSSL on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14361569), [Updating openssl in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18752409), [Python referencing old SSL version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24323858), [Python and OpenSSL version reference issue on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37690054), [Python 3.3 and Installing PyOpenSSL on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21899573), [Using Python with homebrew on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25441252), etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL 1.0.2 and OpenSSL 1.1.0 are not compatible at the API level. This means that you cannot simply relink Python against the new libssl and libcrypto. Instead you need to rebuild Python with the new libssl and libcrypto, as described in [How do I compile Python 3.4 with custom OpenSSL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23548188/how-do-i-compile-python-3-4-with-custom-openssl) or [Building Python with SSL support in non-standard location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5937337/building-python-with-ssl-support-in-non-standard-location).