# Python Openssl not linked with brew

Tags: python, openssl, homebrew

My brew OpenSSL version is 1.0.2l and my Python OpenSSL version is 9.8. I've been trying to solve this issue for hours now. I've tried changing the path in the .bash profile, I've tried uninstalling and then reinstalling

```
python --with-brewed-openssl
```

I've updated/upgraded/pruned/doctored brew, I've tried linking openssl with the following command

```
brew link openssl --force
```

but that results in this error for both 1.0.2l and 1.0.1f,

```
Linking keg-only openssl means you may end up linking against the 
insecure,
deprecated system OpenSSL while using the headers from Homebrew's 
openssl.
Instead, pass the full include/library paths to your compiler e.g.:
-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib
```

I've tried creating symlinks for certain files (although I'm not sure what this was really doing) ... I don't know what else to try. My python version is 2.7.13_1.

Comment: [How do I install pyOpenSSL on Mac OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14361569), [Updating openssl in python 2.7](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18752409), [Python referencing old SSL version](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24323858), [Python and OpenSSL version reference issue on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/37690054), [Python 3.3 and Installing PyOpenSSL on a Mac](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21899573), [Using Python with homebrew on OS X](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25441252), etc...

Comment: Also see [Homebrew refusing to link OpenSSL](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38670295), [Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661), [How to install latest version of openssl Mac OS X El Capitan](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35129977), [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/126830), [Openssl installation using HomeBrew fails](http://superuser.com/q/486389), etc.

Answer (score 0):

As Homebrew tells you, OpenSSL is deprecated and insecure; that’s why it prevents you from linking it.

The only solution you have left is to [build Python from source](https://docs.python.org/2/using/unix.html#building-python) and pass it additional flags at the `./configure` step, as suggested by the Homebrew error message.